# SCons Fails to Detect Visual Studio Build 2017 Tools on Windows 7

Tags: python, c++, windows, visual-studio, scons

I'm trying to Compile Godot Engine - [Godot Engine](https://www.godotengine.org/) which is a 3D Game Engine made with C++. 
According to the Latest Godot Docs - [Compiling Godot on Windows](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/development/compiling/compiling_for_windows.html),
I was trying to Compile Godot on my 32 bit Windows 7 Ultimate PC.

I installed Scons from Official Sources using Command -

> ./setup.py install

So, I did installed successfully without any error.

Then I Downloaded Visual C++ Build Tools and Installed it, the Prompt also works fine.

I installed Python2.7 in the directory C:\python27\
Using -

> python --version

Also, seems that it's working correctly.

But, When I open The Bash Prompt of Visual Studio C++ with present Directory I run these Commands -

```
cd.
cd \godot-master\
C:/python2.7/scons.bat p=windows
```

I'm greeted with some strange error, the

```
C:\godot-gles2\godot-gles2>C:/python27/scons.bat p=windows
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers mos
t likely not set correctly
File "C:\godot-gles2\godot-gles2\SConstruct", line 3, in <module>

scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers mos
t likely not set correctly
File "C:\godot-gles2\godot-gles2\SConstruct", line 71, in <module>
Configuring for Windows: target=debug, bits=default
Found MSVC compiler: x86
Compiled program architecture will be a 32 bit executable. (forcing bits=32).
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str':
  File "C:\godot-gles2\godot-gles2\SConstruct", line 327:
    detect.configure(env)
  File "./platform/windows\detect.py", line 343:
    configure_msvc(env, manual_msvc_config)
  File "./platform/windows\detect.py", line 196:
    env.Append(CPPPATH=[os.getenv("WindowsSdkDir") + "/Include"])

C:\godot-gles2\godot-gles2>
```

What's the problem here? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You should probably run it from Visual Studio Tools command prompt.

Comment: @VTT I tried that

Comment: Which version of SCons? VS 2017 support was introduced in SCons 3.0.0, though I'd recommend 3.0.1. (Also note you can use 3.0.1 with either py2.7 or py 3.5+)